# Reading XML Values

Tags: php, xml

I have this XML Contents

`print_r($xmlapi->api2_query($account, "Cron", "listcron"));` Shows this XML

```
SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [apiversion] => 2
    [data] => Array (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [command] => COMMAND1.php
                [count] => 1
            )
        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [command] => COMMAND2.php
                [count] => 2
            )
        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [count] => 3
            )
    )
    [event] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        ( [result] => 1 )
    [func] => listcron
    [module] => Cron
    [postevent] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
        ( [result] => 1 )
    [preevent] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        ( [result] => 1 )
 )
```

I am trying to get the values of all `[command]`, but Im getting a fatal error

```
    $oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlapi->api2_query($account, "Cron", "listcron"));
    if ($oXML->data->count() > 0) {
        foreach($oXML->data as $v) {
            echo $v->command."<br />";
        }
    }
```

Please help, I need to retrieve all the values of `[command]`

**Edit:**

Sorry I thought this can be called XML but someone pointed out that this is a `print_r of an object` and I have made it work using this code

```
foreach($x as $obj){
    echo $obj->command."<br />";
}
```

Thank you

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Wanna provide the source XML to make life easier?

Comment: cPanel API for Cron Jobs

Comment: This is the error :  Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in ....:71 Stack trace: #0 ...(71): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('\n \n \n ...') #1 {main} thrown in

Answer (score 0):

You will just have to use

```
$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement(XML_VAR_HERE);
$result = $oXML->xpath('//command');

foreach ($result as $each) {
    echo $each->nodeValue;
}
```